# Como tratar erro ao excluir um registro do BD, o qual possui uma chave estrangeira, PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Bom dia pessoal, alguém saberia me indicar a melhor forma de tratar o seguinte erro:
[image: erro retornado]

O seguinte erro ocorre quando por exemplo, possuo um cliente em uma tabela do BD e em outra tabela possuo um orçamento referenciando este cliente, quando tento excluir o cliente ele apresenta esse erro, o que esta correto eu realmente nao quero deletar esse cliente para manter a integridade do BD.

O que eu quero é que esse erro seja apresentado de uma forma melhor para o usuário, algo em forma de uma mensagem explicando o por que de não ser possível excluir o cliente.

Estou utilizando PHP e codeigniter pra fazer esse pequeno sistema.

Edit, códigos utilizados:

Controller:

```
function deletar($pcod) {

        /* Executa a função deletar do modelo passando como parâmetro o id da pessoa */
        if ($this->model->deletar($pcod)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-warning'> Produto deletado com sucesso</div>");
                redirect('produtos');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Erro ao deletar Produto</div>");
            }
    }
```

Model:

```
function deletar($pcod) {
        $this->db->where('pcod', $pcod);
        return $this->db->delete('produtos');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acontece que o CI não trabalha muito bem com Try Catch, uma forma é desabilitar o debug para queries, que faz retornar este erro na tela e fazer a validação com as próprias ferramentas do mesmo. Uma solução seria algo com isto:

```
<?php

function deletar($pcod) {
    $this->db->where('pcod', $pcod);    

    $db_debug = $this->db->db_debug; //salve a configuração
    $this->db->db_debug = FALSE; //desabilita o debug para consultas

    if ( !$this->db->delete('produtos') )
    {
        $error = $this->db->error();

        // Tratativa de erro aqui
        /*
         * Seu código...
         */
        $this->db->db_debug = $db_debug; //restaure a configuração de debug

        return $alguma_coisa_que_queira_retornar;
    }

    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Comment: só pra confirmar se eu entendi eu colocaria este código no meu modal ? minha sql esta da seguinte forma: 
    `function deletar($pcod) {
     $this->db->where('pcod', $pcod);
 return $this->db->delete('produtos');
 }`

Comment: Poste a parte do código onde faz o delete, vou inserir no ponto correto para realizar o teste.

Comment: Post Editado com os código

Comment: Alterei o código, tente realizar o teste e veja se vai lhe atender.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a melhor saída seja usar um bloco try catch:

```
try {
    //coloque aqui sua query 
    //TO DO
}

catch (MySQLException $e) {
    // mysql exception - trate aqui a váriavel abaixo para exibir o erro como quiser
    $e->getMessage();
}
```